# C# BitConverter outputs wrong double value when compared to equivalent Java code

Tags: java, c#, arrays

I am trying to convert a Java function to C#, but I just can't figure it out. The function is supposed to convert a byte array into a double.

Hypothetically these two functions should do the same thing, but they don't.

I've tried using the BitConverter in C#, but that just returns the wrong double.

```
static double readBytes(RandomAccessFile in){ 

    byte a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h; 

    a = in.readByte(); 
    b = in.readByte(); 
    c = in.readByte(); 
    d = in.readByte(); 
    e = in.readByte();
    f = in.readByte();
    g = in.readByte();
    h = in.readByte();
    byte[] ba = { h, g, f, e, d, c, b, a }; 

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(ba)); 
    double x = dis.readDouble(); 

    return x; 
}
```

The converted C# function: (this one returns the wrong double)

```
protected internal static double readBytes(FileStream @in)
{
    byte a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
    a = (byte)@in.ReadByte();
    b = (byte)@in.ReadByte();
    c = (byte)@in.ReadByte();
    d = (byte)@in.ReadByte();
    e = (byte)@in.ReadByte();
    f = (byte)@in.ReadByte();
    g = (byte)@in.ReadByte();
    h = (byte)@in.ReadByte();
    byte[] ba = { h, g, f, e, d, c, b, a };
    double doub = BitConverter.ToDouble(ba, 0);
    return doub;
}
```

For the byte array = `{64, -6, -51, 112, -93, -41, 10, 61}` in Java I get the double = 109783.04 (which is the right converesion) and in C# I get 1.19203925203128E-14

Comment: Have you tried flipping the array order?

Comment: Same machine, or at least, same processor?  Endian-ness can make a big difference.  Create a `struct` with `LayoutKind` set to explicit, effectively creating a union between a double and 8 bytes.  Set the double to 109783.04 and see what the bytes look like.

Comment: Quick test in the C# interactive console:
`BitConverter.GetBytes(109783.04)` returns
`byte[8] { 61, 10, 215, 163, 112, 205, 250, 64 }` so it's reversed compared to Java apparently

Comment: Yep, I just reversed the order of the elements in the byte array and now it works just fine. Thank you guys so-so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse the order of the bytes. This has to do with the difference between Little Endian and Big Endian, which is whether the least significant byte comes first or last-- you can read more about it by googling.

Java stores things in big endian. If your system is in little endian, you need to reverse the bytes before you convert. BitConverter offers a method to determine endian-ness. For instance:

```
        // assuming we're starting with a big-endian byte[]
        // we check if we're using little endian, and if so convert the byte[] to little endian (by reversing its order) before doing the double conversion
        byte[] b = new byte[] { 64, 256-6, 256 - 51, 112, 256 - 93, 256 - 41, 10, 61 };
        bool little = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian;
        if (little)
        {
            byte[] nb = new byte[b.Length];
            for(int i =0; i<b.Length; i++)
            {
                nb[i] = b[b.Length - 1 - i];
            }
            double doub = BitConverter.ToDouble(nb, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            double doub = BitConverter.ToDouble(b, 0);
        }
```

Comment: better  use `Array.Reverse(b);` as described in the documentation of `BitConverter`